# Have same action for before submit and after submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know if it possible to have a same action, for example Users#connexion, and have for this a GET request which give the form for the connexion, and from the same action, a POST one for use the data send by the form.

Because for the moment I've a Users#connexion action, which connect a user, and an empty action Users#getconnect, which route to the form.

**Connect Users#action**

```
def connect
    if usr = User.find_by(:student_number, params['student_number']) && usr.password == params['password']
      session[:user] = usr 
      puts "connexion OK"
    else
      puts "Fail connexion"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Connect!' }
    end
  end
```

**getConnect**

```
def getConnect
  
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get '/connexion', to: 'users#getConnect'
  post '/connexion', to: 'users#connect'
```

EDIT:
Okay so It was very simple, your answer work, shame on me...

```
def connect
    if request.post?
      if usr = User.find_by(:student_number, params['student_number']) && usr.password == params['password']
        session[:user] = usr 
        puts "connexion OK"
      else
        puts "Fail connexion"
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'Connect!' }
      end  
    end
  end
```

And yes thanks for the comment, effectively I don't need the "else" statement, the view is rendering automatically!

Comment: Please read this [post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) about Stack Overflow question formatting. You need to at least include code that shows where you are in the problem.

Comment: okay I will add it, but it's not really a problem related to code.

Comment: If you have a view file named `users/getConnect`, you don't need the method in the controller. It will serve the view automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def connect    
    if request.post?
      #Something
    else
      #Something else
    end
end
```